# Performance difference between defining a block object in a method and as a class variable in java

Tags: java, android, performance

Let's say that I have the following Java code:

```
class MyClass{
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            //Do stuff here...
        }
    }
    void method1(){
        new Handler().post(runnable);
    }

    void method2(){
        new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //Do same stuff here...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

method1() uses a final Runnable that is defined as a class variable once, as the object is created. method2() defines and uses the same runnable every time it's called.

Assuming that the code inside the runnable is A LOT, and these methods get called very often on a mobile device, where the slightest performance gain is appreciated:

Is there any difference between method1 and method2 as far as performance goes?  I'm writing an android app and I have many methods that define and use runnables and listeners. I'm trying to trim as much performance overhead as possible, so I was wondering if this makes any difference? If maybe I should define the listeners and runnables as final (maybe static in some cases) class variables and then use them (but only once)? I mean, apart from code readablity, maintenance etc, I'm strickly taking about performance here.

Comment: if they're called often maybe you shouldn't create a Handler instance every time

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 does not use the same runnable-  each call will be a different instance of that annonymous Runnable class.

But that said-  you're talking a micro, micro optimization if there is any difference between the two.  If the two runnables have the same code, that code would take the same amount of time to run.  The only difference would possibly be at instantiation time of the runnable.  Which is such a tiny percentage of the time it takes to create the runnable, post it, wait for it to cycle to the front of the queue, and execute that you shouldn't be worrying about it.

If you're looking for optimizations, you shouldn't be looking at this type of thing-  look for places where you can use different algorithms with better performance, or different data structures.  The time you'll save from that will dwarf what you'll save from concerns like this.  If you actually think this is a problem, run a profiler and see where you're actually spending your time and fix that.

Comment: Well, that's just an example. I'm mostly instantiating listeners in onCreateView of Dialogs and Fragments, so I want these functions to return as fast as possible because they have to do with UI. Generally the app runs fine, I don't have any problems, I was just curious about the instantiation time. Is it at all different?